# PayPal SEPA Payment button not showing

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal and want to add the payment method SEPA on my current website.
Here are some examples I have followed:

1. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/standalone-buttons/#funding-sources
2. https://demo.paypal.com/de/demo/go_platform/pcRestServerV2/paymentOptions

So basically I'm not getting SEPA button as displayed [here](https://prnt.sc/uu07io) on above 2nd link.

**Here is my code that helps you to identify what I'm doing wrong.**

```
    var FUNDING_SOURCES = [
    paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
    paypal.FUNDING.VENMO,
    paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT,
    paypal.FUNDING.CARD,
    paypal.FUNDING.SEPA,
    ];
FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function(fundingSource) {

    // Initialize the buttons
    var button = paypal.Buttons({
        fundingSource: fundingSource
    });

    // Check if the button is eligible
    if (button.isEligible()) {

        // Render the standalone button for that funding source
        button.render('#paypalCheckoutContainer');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are checking for and rendering particular funding sources? You can let PayPal handle that automatically instead of a forEach loop.  Basically, use the simpler code at; https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

If you are not located in a country that defaults to showing SEPA, add `&buyer-country=DE` to the SDK script query string line when testing in sandbox mode. Only do this for testing other countries in sandbox mode, it is not a valid parameter in live. The buyer's country will be auto detected in live.

Comment: Yes I'm rendering buttons because by default they are not showing SEPA button as shown in the example above, in your link there also not showing the SEPA button

Comment: Rendering specific buttons will *not* make SEPA appear. That is not how it works. SEPA can only appear if the buyer is eligible. Please see my answer.

Comment: Can you help me how can I add fundingSource on buttons?
E.g `paypal.Buttons({  fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.SEPA});`

Comment: What do you mean "add" a funding source? If the buyer is eligible, it will be shown using the basic code at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client .  There is no need to do anything at all with funding sources, unless you want to RESTRICT funding sources.